# Decompose elements in $\Gamma_0(N)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, modular-forms, modular-group

Consider the groups
\begin{align*}
  \Gamma_0(N)
\; &:= \;
  \biggl\{
    \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})
    \;:\;
    c \equiv 0 \mod N
  \biggr\}
\\
  \Gamma_\infty
\; &:= \;
  \biggl\{
    \begin{pmatrix} \pm 1 & n \\ 0 & \pm 1 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})
    \;:\;
    n \in \mathbb{Z}
  \biggr\}
.
\end{align*}
Via Sage or GAP (see for example https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/congruence/doc/chap4.html#X79C44528864044C5) we can compute the generators of $\Gamma_0(N)$, where I am interested in how one can decompose any given element $\gamma \in \Gamma_\infty \backslash \Gamma_0(N)$ in terms of those generators.

Given an $\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} * & * \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma_\infty \backslash \Gamma_0(N)$, we only need to care about the decomposition of $(c, d)$ by right-side multiplication.

My current method have been to

1. Make sure that all the generators $g_1, \ldots, g_k$ are on the form $T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and possibly $J = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$, and the rest being on the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ such that $a, c$ have the same sign, and opposite sign of $b, d$.
2. Make the transform $\gamma \mapsto \gamma \, T^n = \gamma_1$ such that the $c(\gamma_1) = c(\gamma)$ and $|d(\gamma_1)| < |c(\gamma_1)|$ where $d(\gamma_1)$ has the opposite sign to $c(\gamma_1)$.
3. Try to minimize $c(\gamma_1)$ by looking at the ratio $| d(\gamma_1) / c(\gamma_1)|$ and try to find a generator $g$ (or its inverse $g^{-1}$) which has a similar ratio $|a(g) / c(g)|$. When such a generator is found, map $\gamma_1 \mapsto \gamma_1 g = \gamma_2$.
4. "Repeat" previous step until $\gamma_i$ can be expressed in terms of a generator.

Now, as an example consider $\Gamma_0(10)$, which is generated by the elements
\begin{align*}
  T &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\\
  U_1 &= \begin{pmatrix} 3 & -1 \\ 10 & -3 \end{pmatrix}
\\
  U_2 &= \begin{pmatrix} 19 & -7 \\ 30 & -11 \end{pmatrix}
\\
  U_3 &= \begin{pmatrix} 11 & -5 \\ 20 & -9 \end{pmatrix}
\\
  U_4 &= \begin{pmatrix} 7 & -5 \\  10 & -7 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
whose inverses are
\begin{align*}
  T^{-1} &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\\
  U_1^{-1} &= \begin{pmatrix} -3 & 1 \\ -10 & 3 \end{pmatrix}
\\
  U_2^{-1} &= \begin{pmatrix} -11 & 7 \\ -30 & 19 \end{pmatrix}
\\
  U_3^{-1} &= \begin{pmatrix} -9 & 5 \\ -20 & 11 \end{pmatrix}
\\
  U_4^{-1} &= \begin{pmatrix} -7 & 5 \\  -10 & 7 \end{pmatrix}
.
\end{align*}

Let's say we are given $\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} * & * \\  10 & 9 \end{pmatrix}$, which we want to decompose. After step one, we find $\gamma_1 = \gamma \, T^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} * & * \\  10 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$. The closest ratio we find is given by $U_1$, and after this step we find $\gamma_2 = \gamma_1 U_1 = \begin{pmatrix} * & * \\ 20 & -7 \end{pmatrix}$. Here the closest ratio is given by $U_2^{-1}$, where $\gamma_3 = \gamma_2 U_2^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} * & * \\ -10 & 7 \end{pmatrix} \sim U_4$. Thus
\begin{equation*}
\gamma = U_4 U_2 U_1^{-1}\, T.
\end{equation*}

I have found this algorithm to work for many examples, but not for every example. For prime $N$ I have seem to find an extension to this technique which has worked for example I have tried.

However, one example that I am not able to find any decomposition for is
\begin{equation*}
\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} * & * \\ 40 & -3 \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma_0(10).
\end{equation*}

Does anyone know how to decompose this $\gamma$? How can I find a more general technique for finding decompositions?

Comment: I don't think the $[40\quad-3]$ row can be decomposed at all.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire So you think the generators I've been given are wrong?